# Converting pre-ADF coverages to current shapefiles?

Tags: shapefile, convert, esri-coverage-format

I have a set of old coverage files, published at 1995-1996 in a CDROM by an official mapping authority. They were, therefore, made with ArcView 1.x and don't have the ".adf" extension. The files that come into the single folder are: ARC, ARX, CNT, CNX, DBLBND, DBLTIC, LAB, LOG, PAL, PAR, PAX, TXT and TXX (all without any exntension), besides a PAT.DBF.

I've tried to import that into ArcGIS 10, without success. I've tried to open it in ArcView 3.3 by adding it as a New Theme, but nothing is shown as well. I've tried to convert them with ogr2ogr and with ArcINFO2Shape utility (deliverd at: http://freegeographytools.com/2007/converting-e00-vector-data-to-shapefiles-a-free-and-fairly-painless-approach). Nothing seems to work. I also don't have access to a an older ArcWorstation.

Is there any way to do achieve such a task?

PS: I am aware of the other two questions asking similar things here at the GIS-Stackexchange. My question, however, deals with even older non-adf extension data and, as described, the processes being discussed in the other related questions did not apply to my data.

Comment: ArcView 1.0 couldn't make any files -- strictly read-only.  If you have a coverage directory without the parallel info directory, your data is likely lost.  Note that pre-6.0 workspaces worked the same as post-6.0, just with different naming conventions.

Comment: @Vince Didn't PC Arc/Info not use an INFO folder in early versions?

Comment: I think they're PC ARC/INFO coverages which aren't the same as ArcInfo workstation and Vince and I can't think of any way to convert them without the actual PC ARC/INFO software. Sorry.

Comment: Found a possible translator [here](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/samples-and-utilities/view/productid/33/metaid/569). It has to run on a 32-bit Windows OS which I don't have access to right now.

Comment: @mkennedy, that looks promising, or at least not dangerous as it's an Esri product. ArcGis will still read coverages (of the ArcInfo type) there's a published format here http://avce00.maptools.org/docs/v7_bin_cover.html that would help in absolute desperation. Have you considered copying to a hard drive and adding the extenstions to the file names? I remember around '98 running into a situation where data was exported to a *coverage* but the extensions were left off, perhaps they were generated with similar software.